# Insta360 Studio incorrectly displays .insv 360 video file as a black video, static, or distorted monocular video

Tags: video

I have a Insta360 video recorded on an Insta360 One X, and I'm trying to get it to display correctly. The video was displaying and exporting without difficulty until I updated Insta360 studio to 2021 (v4.0.0), and displayed correctly on my phone through the bluetooth connection to the camera.

Now insta360 gives me a flickery illegible mostly black screen as a preview -- basically acting like the video is unreadable. I back-updated Insta360 Studio to v3.6.8 and then it displays as a distorted and badly stitched video, seemingly only through one of the two camera lenses. There's a second mystery video file, seemingly recorded simultaneously, that displays in Insta360 studio as a monocular fish-eye with no manipulation options in Insta360 Studio.

I talked to Insta360 tech support, who advised me to turn CUDA off in the settings. That setting doesn't exist on the mac version of 4.0.0, but does on the windows version of 3.6.8. On the windows version of 3.6.8 it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I had renamed the files at the same time as updating Insta360 studio. The camera produces a pair of files, one for each lens, and has a naming convention that lets Insta360 studio pair and stitch them. The naming convention is underscore delimited, and requires the same pattern of underscores as the camera-generated file name. Also, the files have to have the same name except for having "00" and "10" in the right place in the pattern. Below is my tabulation of insta360 studio behavior with different file names. [image: Insta360 file name test results] Correct display requires four underscores in the pattern of "p_q_r_00_s.insv" and "p_q_r_10_s.insv", where at least p,q,r,s can be empty or text containing spaces. So some text followed by three underscores, then "00_.insv" / "10_.insv" works.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reformat the image here using the (relatively) new [table markdown support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)? Images present many problems from both an accessibility and searchability point of view. Thanks!